# Why Isn't the ML Estimator (MLE) in MIMO Spatial Multiplexing Obtained by the Least Squares Solution?

Tags: digital-communications, estimation, least-squares, maximum-likelihood-estimation, mimo

In the simplest scenario of MIMO spatial multiplexing: $$\mathbf{y} = H\mathbf{s} + \mathbf{n}$$
where:     $\mathbf{s}=[s_0,s_1,...s_{M-1}] \\\mathbf{y}=[y_0,y_1,...y_{N-1}]$

$\mathbf{n}=[n_0,n_1,...n_{N-1}]$ is zero mean complex normal independent Random vector

$M$ transmit antennas, $N$ receive antennas where $N\geq M$

The maximum likelihood solution is:
$$\tilde{\mathbf{s}} = \arg\min_{\mathbf{s} \in QPSK^M} ||\mathbf{y}-H\mathbf{s}||^2$$

Now, my textbook says that due to the fact that in this scenario $H^{*}H$ is not a diagonal matrix, the least squares solution followed by proccesing is not optimal, but I can't see why this is true.
To my understanding, denoting the LS solution as  $\hat{s}=(H^{*}H)^{-1}H^{*}\mathbf{y}$
I can write:
$$  ||\mathbf{y}-H\mathbf{s}||^2 = ||\mathbf{y}-H\hat{s}+H\hat{s}-H\mathbf{s}||^2 = \\||y-H\hat{s}||^2 + ||H(\hat{s}-s)||^2 + 2Re[(y-H\hat{s})^{*}H(\hat{s}-s)]$$

Now, by substituing the LS solution the $Re$ part vanishes.
And the problem reduces to 
$$\arg\min_{s\in QPSK^{M}}|\hat{s}-s|^2$$
So I don't get why the ML is not optimal is this case.
Can anyone please clarify?
Thanks

edit: screen shot from the book
[image]

Comment: Could you tell the noise properties?

Comment: Regular zero mean complex normal independent random vector

Comment: Could you share the book name and a screen shot of the page you're talking about? I think I know what's the catch, yet just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, I added, it from a course thought by Dr Doron Ezri - OFDM-MIMO course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must attention to the written text.
It doesn't say the ML isn't optimal, what it says is that the problem isn't regular LS problem but Least squares problem with Constraints.

The constraints make analytic solution infeasible and hence in order to solve it one must go through any signal in the space of valid signals and mark the one which minimizes the LS problem.

What they mean that the regular LS solution result doesn't necessarily yield a solution in the space of valid space of signals and even taking the closes one to the solution isn't optimal.

So we have the problem the constrained problem:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{s} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| H s - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & s \in {QPSK}^{M}
\end{align*}$$

Which its solution is optimal.

What they say isn't optimal is solving:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{s} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| H s - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\end{align*}$$

And then find $ s \in {QPSK}^{M} $ as you'd do in MIMO.
Namely, the greedy method (Do LS while ignoring the constraint and then apply the constraint) isn't optimal.

Yet the problem is that there is no analytic or efficient way to solve the Constraint LS problem but doing brute force search which isn't feasible.

I agree the text isn't clear about making this observation.
Yet it well known in the optimization field that solving in this greedy 2 step method isn't guaranteed to be optimal.

**Remark**
I found a link to the PDF - [Doron Ezri - MIMO OFDM Lecture Notes](https://www.scribd.com/document/187975631/MIMO-Course301011). What I talked about can be seen in part 5.4.

Comment: I don't get it, basically your'e saying that using regular LS yields post processing which is far to computationally heavy and thus not optimal?

Comment: I tried making it clearer. Read the answer again. By the way, what's the name of the book?

Comment: Theoretically, If ignoring computational complexity, the greedy way using the LS would be optimal, right?
Its from  a course by Dr Doron Ezri - OFDM-MIMO

Comment: Yes, the constraint problem is optimal given AWGN. Is there a site for the course?

Comment: No site for the course, sorry

Comment: I found a link to the PDF - [Doron Ezri - MIMO OFDM Lecture Notes](https://www.scribd.com/document/187975631/MIMO-Course301011). What I talked about can be seen in part 5.4.

Comment: So in ZF we apply LS and then for each symbol individually we find its closest match? where the actual ML would have to find the complete vector of symbols all at once?
How is that related to the $H^{*}H$ not being diagonal?

Comment: Because if it is diagonal it means it is an ensemble of SISO.